# parsing sql CAST xml

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012, rds

I have a table with an xml column.
i want to parse it for a specific keys in the xml,which i accomplish by doing the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
 CAST([PlatformInfo] as xml).value('(/PlatformInfo/@Device)[1]', 'varchar(max)')  as Device ,
 CAST([PlatformInfo] as xml).value('(/PlatformInfo/@SDKv)[1]', 'varchar(max)')  as SDKv 
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[HISTORY_TB]
```

Now i want to sort it and i always get an error.
How can i sort the custom columns that i created as Device and SDKv ?
How can i sort it by a specific value?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code, the error message, and the expected results.

Comment: the code is displayed in the original question, I tried doing in the end of the  code block " ORDER BY SDKv or @SDKv by i am surly doing something wrong

Comment: You said I want to sort, so, I suppose that you have a sorting code which gives an error.

Comment: If your column already **is** of datatype `XML`, then this `CAST` is not necessary: `CAST([PlatformInfo] as xml)` ...

Comment: The datatype is not set to an xml .  also i see now that the query is taking 2 minutes but finally succeded with  "ORDER BY SDKv" or "ORDER BY Device"

Comment: how to i order by a specific device name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create table #companyname(name varchar(max))
Insert into #companyname (name) values
('<name>US Concrete Inc</name>'),
('<name>Digitiliti Inc</name>'),
('<name>Printron Inc</name>'),
('<name>Wesco Financial, LLC</name>'),
('<name>Fusion Restaurant Group Inc</name>')

select * from (
select top 4 CAST(name as xml).value('(/name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as t 
from #companyname )tbl
order by tbl.t
```

Similarly :

```
 Select * from (
    SELECT TOP 1000 
CAST([PlatformInfo] as xml).value('(/PlatformInfo/@Device)[1]', 'varchar(max)')  as Device ,
CAST([PlatformInfo] as xml).value('(/PlatformInfo/@SDKv)[1]', 'varchar(max)')  as SDKv 
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[HISTORY_TB]) dertbl
order by dertbl.Device,dertbl.SDKv
```

Comment: This is the error i got   `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'Device'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'SDKv'. `